# problem with detecting the single-color objects

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

which package can be used to detect the single-color objects?
I already used re_kinect_object_detector package and it works well with textured objects but it can't work successfully with single-color objects

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49419/problem-with-detecting-the-single-color-objects/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can't really do full object detection, but you could use [cmvision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cmvision) to get started just detecting single-color blobs. After that, you would probably have to apply some criteria to distinguish different object, depending on your application.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-29**:
[This page](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision) gives some more details on how to use this package.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-11-30**:
thanks a lot,but I want to use package that can detect single-color and texture objects perfectly and share this knowledge on roboearth server...can you help me ?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-30**:
I don't know about any released packages that can help you with that, sorry.